# How do I define interfaces in managed C++/CLI

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli

Can we define interfaces in C++ using Visual Studio?

If yes, what would be an example of defining interfaces in C++?

Comment: Please define what you mean more precisely

Comment: Do you want to create interfaces that can be implemented in managed code? or interfaces that will be used exclusively by C++?

Answer (score 23):

In managed C++, this is the syntax for a managed interface.

```
using namespace System;

interface class IFoo
{
    String^ GetName();
};
```

Comment: It's worth noting that the syntax for a property is:  `property String^ Name;`

Answer (score 1):

C++ does not have a concept of "interface" per se. They are usually emulated with abstract classes with pure virtual functions. Moreover, `class`es are usually substituted with `struct`s, since default access modifier for those is `public`. Hence,

```
struct IFoo
{
    virtual void Bar() = 0;
}
```

Also, see [this](http://www.ddj.com/cpp/184401848).

Comment: What about the memory leak you are causing at the destruction of the object!  Base classes MUST have a public virtual destructor or a protected non-virtual destructor.

Comment: @Anton Gogolev if you have virtual memebers you should have a virtual destructor